# Unpacking objects individually from a TCP stream

Tags: python, sockets, serialization, tcp, msgpack

I would like to read one by one the objects coming from a TCP stream, preferably using the [MessagePack](https://pypi.org/project/msgpack/0.6.2/) library.

On one side I have a *client* that, at each iteration of a loop:

- computes a point location (tuple)
- packs that location and sends it through a socket

On the other side, a *server* that:

- receive the data when client is detected
- unpack that data

For now I am storing the data in a buffer on reception, then proceed to unpacking when the stream is over. My problem is that I need to unpack the tuples one by one **as they are sent**. In other words I would like to read the data **in real time** without putting it in a buffer.

Provided it is possible, how could I achieve this using MessagePack ?

*-- client side --*

```
#Python3.7
import socket
import msgpack
import math

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 9000

den = 40
rad = 100
theta = math.tau / den

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT)) #connect to server

    for step in range(den):
        x = math.cos(i*theta) * rad
        y = math.sin(i*theta) * rad
        data = msgpack.packb((x, y), use_bin_type = True)
        sock.sendall(data)
```

*-- server side --*

```
#Jython2.7 <-- Python 2.7 compatible only
from io import BytesIO
import msgpack
import socket

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 9000

buf = BytesIO()

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
connection, address = s.accept()


while True:
    try:
        data = connection.recv(1024)
        buf.write(data)

    except:
        buf.seek(0)
        unpacker = msgpack.Unpacker(buf, use_list=False, raw=False)
        for unpacked in unpacker:
            print(unpacked)
        buf = BytesIO()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See "Stream Unpacking" section in the README:
https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-python#streaming-unpacking

You can do like this:

```
unpacker = msgpack.Unpacker(use_list=False, raw=False)

while True:
    data = connection.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    unpacker.feed(data)
    for unpacked in unpacker:
        print(unpacked)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the swift reply. Is 1024 mandatory in this case ? Or can it be lowered (32 or 16) ?

Comment: 1024 is just an example.  You can choose number which is good for your application.